# c# update database isn't working

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

So I've searched the net to find a solution and what I found is that when we execute F5 in visual studio, it actually copies the original database into a new one and it uses the copy in the code so the changes you'd have made wouldn't be there and they told me to set the database properties to "Copy if newer" and it isn't working, I don't get any error messages but the original is not being updated.

I made a test to see if this code was updating at least the copy and it is...
After running my application when I see the database the changes aren't there 
So I want to update the original database how do I do that?

```
      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NembManagement.Properties.Settings.NembDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Alunos SET Nome = @a WHERE Id=1", connection))
        {
            DataTable AlunosInfo = new DataTable();
            connection.Open();
            command.Prepare();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a","aff");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //test to see if it was updating the copy and it is
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Alunos WHERE Alunos.Id=1 ", connection);
            adapter.Fill(AlunosInfo);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Please paste your `connectionString`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution somehow, i changed my database property Copy to nevercopy and i got another error saying that connection could not be opened so i solved this one by correcting the connection string in the app config